# OAuth in Google Data API using Java

Tags: java, oauth, google-calendar-api

Does anyone know any web application example where Oauth has been used in with google data API?

Comment: None that I know of, but you can always check the API for OAuth with Google data API (http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/oauth.html)

Comment: I have checked that example, somehow it is incomplete. It just doesn't work when it comes to authorizing the request token. How will I come to in program if user has decided to grant the access or not? There is nothing regarding that.

Comment: Ok, then try this then (http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html)

Comment: well I have tried this too. My question is when someone is redirected to google authorization page and they enter their user id , password and grants the access, how will I come to know if they have granted access or denied the access in program I am writing? I need to get back authorized request token from callback URL.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand (correct me if I'm wrong). In order to get the request token back set the `oauth_callback` to the absolute path where the `oauth_token` will be appended to the `oath_callback`.

From (http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html)

> **Extracting the token from the callback URL**
>
> When Google redirects back to your
>   application, the oauth_token is
>   appended to the "oauth_callback_url"
>   URL as a query parameter. Your
>   application should then extract the
>   token value from its URL query
>   parameter and re-establish the oauth
>   parameters.

If you're using Google OAuth helper, then you can try this example.

```
import com.google.gdata.client.docs.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.*;

String CONSUMER_KEY = "example.com";
String CONSUMER_SECRET = "abc123doremi";

GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
oauthParameters.setScope("https://docs.google.com/feeds/");
oauthParameters.setOAuthCallback("http://www.example.com/UpgradeToken.jsp");

GoogleOAuthHelper oauthHelper = new GoogleOAuthHelper(new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());
oauthHelper.getUnauthorizedRequestToken(oauthParameters);
```

This example seemed to have been written inside a JSP. You can use it using Frameworks.

The `oauthParameters.setOAuthCallback()` is where Google added their callback URL path to ensure their token are returned.

Comment: That's what I am exactly trying. My real problem comes when user grants or denies access. How should I catch that event? I need to query for oauth_token from callback_url, but that depends only if user has granted the access.

Comment: What do you mean `when user grants or denies access`?

Comment: well..once I get an authorized URL , I will redirect user to that URL where user provides his login details and he gets the screen where he can grant access to data of that google service or he can deny.

Comment: For that, You can only assign an `oauth_callback` to the authorized URL. If the user denies, you won't get any callback returned to your page. You can only do a callback to a successful user authorization.

Comment: I got your point. Somehow my callback url is one of the authorized page which only logged in users can see. But when oauth_token is appended to callback url after access is granted, it takes back them to login page instead of the page they were before.

Comment: I don't quite follow. If The OAuth Service provider returns to your `oauth_callback` url, then it's working fine. It must be the way you're handling authentication/authorization from your webapp, the logic isn't fine.

Comment: Well, it is definitely working. Somehow I am stuck on how to use callback url. You might get idea what exactly I am looking for in my other question, I asked on stackoverflow.